# calling icons in html from JS

Tags: javascript, icons

So this is my problem... I have icons in JS file like this:

```
 function iconValues() {

// Icon svg-s
var icons = {
   home:
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="-293 385 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M-283 405v-6h4v6h5v-8h3l-10-9 -10 9h3v8H-283z"/></svg>',
  user:
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="409.2" height="409.2" viewBox="0 0 409.2 409.2" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M204.6 216.7c50.7 0 91.7-48.1 91.7-107.4 0-82.2-41.1-107.4-91.7-107.4 -50.7 0-91.7 25.1-91.7 107.4C112.8 168.6 153.9 216.7 204.6 216.7zM407.2 374.7L360.9 270.5c-2.1-4.8-5.8-8.7-10.5-11.1l-71.8-37.4c-1.6-0.8-3.5-0.7-4.9 0.4 -20.3 15.4-44.2 23.5-69.1 23.5 -24.9 0-48.8-8.1-69.1-23.5 -1.4-1.1-3.3-1.2-4.9-0.4L58.8 259.3c-4.6 2.4-8.3 6.4-10.5 11.1L2 374.7c-3.2 7.2-2.5 15.4 1.8 22 4.3 6.6 11.5 10.5 19.4 10.5h362.9c7.9 0 15.1-3.9 19.4-10.5C409.7 390.1 410.4 381.9 407.2 374.7z"/></svg>'
```

I included JS script in html. Now I want to know how to include one of those icons in (li) html? Example:

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html">Home</a> </li>
```

What do I need to write in (li) to show me icon that I need?

Thank you.

Comment: You've kinda limited your options by approaching icons in this way. In my mind, the easiest way to show this icon is to insert it inside a `span` just before the text. That way you can style the `span` instead of the `svg`.

Comment: ok i was think about it as well.. but what do i need to write in span? like:
span id="home"? coz it doesnt show the icon..

Answer (score 1):

for example...

```js
var icons = {
   home:
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="-293 385 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M-283 405v-6h4v6h5v-8h3l-10-9 -10 9h3v8H-283z"/></svg>',
  user:
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="409.2" height="409.2" viewBox="0 0 409.2 409.2" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M204.6 216.7c50.7 0 91.7-48.1 91.7-107.4 0-82.2-41.1-107.4-91.7-107.4 -50.7 0-91.7 25.1-91.7 107.4C112.8 168.6 153.9 216.7 204.6 216.7zM407.2 374.7L360.9 270.5c-2.1-4.8-5.8-8.7-10.5-11.1l-71.8-37.4c-1.6-0.8-3.5-0.7-4.9 0.4 -20.3 15.4-44.2 23.5-69.1 23.5 -24.9 0-48.8-8.1-69.1-23.5 -1.4-1.1-3.3-1.2-4.9-0.4L58.8 259.3c-4.6 2.4-8.3 6.4-10.5 11.1L2 374.7c-3.2 7.2-2.5 15.4 1.8 22 4.3 6.6 11.5 10.5 19.4 10.5h362.9c7.9 0 15.1-3.9 19.4-10.5C409.7 390.1 410.4 381.9 407.2 374.7z"/></svg>',
};

// insert
var target = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-icon-key]');
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
  var key = target[i].getAttribute('data-icon-key');
  if (icons[key]) {
    // if you want to append the icon
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = icons[key];
    target[i].appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    
    // if you want to replace the content of <a>
    //target[i].innerHTML = icons[key];
  }
}
```

```css
a > svg { height: 16px; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="dashboard.html" data-icon-key="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="usermenu.html" data-icon-key="user">User</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### how it works

each `<a>` element that has `data-icon-key` attribute, for example, `foo`, it will be added the icon `icons['foo']`.

Comment: I'm still not sure the advantage of holding the SVG in JS, but this is a good approach.